# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when accessing gisgraphy api

Tags: ajax, api, post, request, cross-domain

Im trying to access gisgraphys api with this code:

```
$('[id$=PlaceOfDeparture]:not(.ui-autocomplete-input)').live('focus', function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://services.gisgraphy.com/fulltext/fulltextsearch?q='+ request.term,
                //data: {
                //    q: request.term
                //},

                success: function(res) {
                    console.log("Success: " + res);
                },
                error: function(res) {
                    console.log("Error: " + res);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

when i do that i get error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://services.gisgraphy.com/fulltext/fulltextsearch?q=viborgsslingan. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'mylocalhost' is therefore not allowed access. 
if i press the link i get the xml in the browser just as i want it. Somehow it wont get to my code. Ive search a bit about the problem but it seems to be a security problem on the gisgraphy server... Is there anything i can do to make this cross-domain access work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ive search a bit about the problem but it seems to be a security problem on the gisgraphy server...

It’s not a security *problem*, rather the other way around. The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) forbids you from requesting data from other domains in JS via AJAX, *unless* the remote domain signals that it wants to explicitly *grant* you access (this is called [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)).

If the service you are accessing doesn’t offer that, and no other format that is not restricted by the SOP – like f.e. JSONP – then you can not get that data client-side via JavaScript.